# Long Division in Java not working as expected

Tags: java, long-integer

```
class LongDiv{
public static void main(String [] args){

    final long x = 24*60*60*1000*1000;
    final long y = 24*60*60*1000;
    System.out.println(x/y);
}
}
```

although the expected answer is 1000, but the javac gives it as 5. Reason?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The long `x` you are creating isn't the value you expected. It is in the integer range. To create longs, use:

```
final long x = 24L*60L*60L*1000L*1000L;
final long y = 24L*60L*60L*1000L;
System.out.println(x/y);
```

The `x` you computed, in the integer range, was `500654080`. This divided by the `y` ( = `86400000`), results in `5.794607407407407...`. Java truncates the decimal part which causes the 5.

By adding an `L` after the number literal, you tell the compiler to compile it as a `long` instead of an `int`. The value for `x` you expected is `86400000000`. But is was compiled as an int.

We can reproduce the wrong value for `x` (`500654080`) by truncating it to an int:

```
// First correct
long x = 24L*60L*60L*1000L*1000L;
/* x = `86400000000`; */
// Now truncate
x &= 0xFFFFFFFFL; // again: don't forget the L suffix
/* x = `500654080` */
```

Comment: Only one of those literals in each expression needs to be a `long`. See @Peter's answer.

Comment: I know, but I think this is a style preference.

Comment: @Martijn: how can i calculate this value 500654080 without the computer!! this question appeared in a written exam!!

Comment: This is a pretty cruel written exam question...  The best I can think of would be to write out the bits of each number and mask them with 0xFFFFFFFF, as @Peter hinted at above.

Comment: @Aakash: If the question was "Why is this value wrong?", you can simply say that `x` is trucated to a int because of the forgotten `L` suffix.

Comment: @Eric: eBay campus recruitment programme!!

Answer (score 5):

The expressions `24*60*60*1000*1000`  is an `int` type not a `long`  What you want is `24L*60*60*1000*1000` which is `long`

This is what you have.

```
final long x = (24*60*60*1000*1000) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
final long y = (24*60*60*1000) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
System.out.println(x/y);
```

what you want is

```
final long x = 24L*60*60*1000*1000;
final long y = 24L*60*60*1000;
System.out.println(x/y);
```

Comment: To be explicit about it you can always do a `1L * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000`.

Comment: In that case you could do `(long) 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000`

Comment: When would the int->long promotion happen?  For 24 or the full (intified) result?

Comment: casting takes precedence over multiplication http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Answer (score 2):

casting (forcing) to long works in case of literal values for the right operand; but the problem persists in case of assigning one long variable to another, as in the below given example:

```
package utils;

public class Utils {

    public static void main(String ... clps){
        Utils.longDivision();
        Utils.doubleDivision();
    }

    private static void doubleDivision(){
        double x=new Long("54321").doubleValue();
        double y=new Long("12345").doubleValue();
        double difference=x - y;
        double percentage=(difference/x)*100.00;
        System.out.println("\nDouble Division ==> X : "+x+" ; Y : "+y+" ; Difference : "+difference+" ; percentage : "+percentage+"\n");
    }

    private static void longDivision(){
        long x=new Long("54321").longValue();
        long y=new Long("12345").longValue();
        long difference=x - y;
        long percentage=(difference/x)*100L;
        System.out.println("\nLong Division ==> X : "+x+" ; Y : "+y+" ; Difference : "+difference+" ; percentage : "+percentage+"\n");
    }

}
```

The only way i could get proper answer is by converting the division of longs into division of doubles. It is very strange why division of longs behaves in such mysterious manner.

longDivision gives the answer as zero whereas the doubleDivision gives the correct answer.

I hope this helps others who encountered similar issues...

Answer (score 1):

`24*60*60*1000*1000` is too large to fit into an `int` and overflows.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one!

The issue is that 24, 60, and 1000 are Java literal *ints*.  Before the values are assigned to x and y, they are truncated to fit in int values.  Try

```
System.out.print(x + ", " + y);
```

to see exactly what I mean.  The quick fix is to make your literals into long values like so:

```
public class LongDiv{
public static void main(String [] args){

    final long x = 24l*60l*60l*1000l*1000l;
    final long y = 24l*60l*60l*1000l;
    System.out.println(x/y);
}
}
```

Comment: Beaten to the punch!  Not quite as tricky as I thought, I guess :)