# How to divide two long variables in java

Tags: java, variables, types, casting

Sorry for the basic question,
 I have to divide the long variable by another long variable, but it returns 0.
Can any one help

```
long a = 3004230;
long b =  6793368;
long c = (a/b)*100;
```

Comment: `long c = (long)((a/(float)b)*100);`

Comment: did you search your problem before asking question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117014/dividing-long-by-long-returns-0 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766120/long-division-in-java-not-working-as-expected or lots of old questions

Comment: Use `long c = (a*100L/b)` if you don't require decimal value,  `long c = (a/b)*100` is evaluated as `(a/b)*100 --> (3004230/6793368)*100 --> (0L)*100 --> c=0` hence it will always be zero whereas `(a*100L/b) --> (300423000/6793368) --> (44L) --> c=44`

Comment: long c = 100L *a/b

Answer (score 56):

### Literal Values and Literal Arithmatic

There are a couple of issues with that code. Firstly, non-floating point **literal values** are of type `int` by default and so `3004230` in your code is an `int`. To explicitly declare it a `long` use `3004230L` instead.

Also, all arithmetic done with non-floating point **literals** returns an `int` result unless one of the variables are casted specifically to a floating point type such as `float` or `double`. As such `(a/b)*100` is less than 1, and therefore is [truncated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation) down to 0 (the floating point values are just cut off). Also, even if it did return the same result you are trying to store it in a `long` which can not store floating point values.

So, you should do something like the following to get the real result.

```
long a = 3004230L; // Use the L notation to declare this literal a long.
long b = 6793368L;
double c = ((double) a/b)*100; /* casting one of the variables to (double) means the result will not be 0 */
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The decimal part of the number is truncated to 0, not rounded down. Cast 0.4 to an `int` and it will be 0, cast 0.99999999999 to an `int` and it will also be 0. The decimal part is removed leaving only the integer part.

Comment: @DanTemple - Good point, will correct my answer.

Comment: There is still a false statement in the comment: "casting your division result to (double) means the result will not be 0". 
If you try to cast the result it is too late because "((double)(a/b))*100 == 0.0".

Still the code is correct because you are actually casting "a" to double and it leads to expected result :)

Comment: @MarekManduch quite right. I have corrected it.

Comment: You don't need the  L part in 3004230L as long as the literal value is within size of an int it will auto-convert it to a long for you from int :)

Answer (score 11):

```
final long a = 3004230;
final long b = 6793368;
final double c = ((double) a / b) * 100;
```

=> c = 44.22298335670907

Answer (score 6):

try it.

```
long a = 3004230;
long b =  6793368;
long c = ((long)((float)a/(float)b)*100); //answer=44
float c = ((long)((float)a/(float)b)*100); //answer=44.1256378
```

Answer (score 4):

obviously the answer will be `0` for above..as you can see when you divide

> 3004230 / 6793368 = 0.442 = 0(when casted to `long` type)

and

> 0 * any number = 0..

to convert it use this

```
double c = (a * 1.0/b)*100.0;
```

you have to use datatype that can store `decimal` value which is `float` or `double`..`long` cannot store decimal numbers

Comment: superb!!, thanks for the basics

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same without casting to a `float`:

```
long a =  3004230L;
long b =  6793368L;
long c = (a * 100L)/b;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing right now is integer division. This will always return an integer/long result. You have to use a float or double to get a floating point result even if you cast it back to integer values afterwards.

```
long c = (long)(a/(float)b*100);
```

Answer (score 1):

The long c you are creating isn't the value you expected. It is in the integer range. To create longs, use

final long c=  3004230L * 6793368L;
By adding an L after the number literal, you tell the compiler to compile it as a long instead of an int.